# SignalR Push notification in Android mobiles

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I have developed a chatting app Using SignalR. Currently I am moving that code to WebAPI for an android application,

When a user sends message to an android user I want to show push notifications on android mobiles. Is its possible to use SignalR as the client in an android app.

I'm seen some of online references like google GCm, ShaperChat but I'm not understanding them.

Answer (score 12):

Yes you can use signalR in your android application. But it will be worth it to configure your application to use signalR when it is in the foreground and then use firebase push notification when the application runs in the background because your signalR connection can be disconnected and then your signalR will not work. So when application is running you should use signalR otherwise use firebase notificaiton system because firebase uses google play service which will always being running on a device.

A simple signalR implementation 
https://github.com/ngocchung/SimpleSignalRClient

Comment: Very good answer thanks a lot for clear clarification. This should be the correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.
first of all make sure your SignalR service is working fine and noted down your token and hub connection, group name from which you can subscribe those calls by invoking them.

1) Made one singleton class

```
public class SignalRSingleton {

private static SignalRSingleton mInstance = null;
public HubConnection mHubConnection;
public HubProxy mHubProxy;

public static SignalRSingleton getInstance(){
    if(mInstance == null)
    {
        mInstance = new SignalRSingleton();
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public void setmHubConnection()
{
    String serverUrl = "http://192.168.1.5:8089/XM/";
    //String serverUrl = "http://192.168.1.184/test";
    mHubConnection = new HubConnection(serverUrl);
}

public void setHubProxy()
{
   /* Credentials credentials = new Credentials() {
        @Override
        public void prepareRequest(Request request) {
            request.addHeader("User-Name", MainActivity.unm);
        }
    };*/

    //mHubConnection.setCredentials(credentials);
    String SERVER_HUB_CHAT = "messages";
    //String SERVER_HUB_CHAT = "Chat";
    mHubProxy = mHubConnection.createHubProxy(SERVER_HUB_CHAT);
}


/**
 * method for clients (activities)
 */
public void sendMessage(String name , String message) {

    String str = "{'RequestMessage':{'PID':'lr1','Password':'GIefhSIC5iBCnxioufbwEw == '},'RequestType':'Login'}";
    String SERVER_METHOD_SEND = "getMessage";
    //String SERVER_METHOD_SEND = "Send";
    mHubProxy.invoke(SERVER_METHOD_SEND,str);
  }
}
```

2) Then implement service

```
public class SignalRService extends Service {
    //private HubConnection mHubConnection;
    //private HubProxy mHubProxy;
    private Handler mHandler; // to display Toast message
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder(); // Binder given to clients
    private SignalRSingleton mInstance;
    final static String MY_ACTION = "MY_ACTION";
    public SignalRService() {

    }
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = SignalRSingleton.getInstance();
    mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    int result = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    startSignalR();
    return result;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mInstance.mHubConnection.stop();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // Return the communication channel to the service.
    startSignalR();
    return mBinder;
}

/**
 * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
 * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
 */
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public SignalRService getService() {
        // Return this instance of SignalRService so clients can call public methods
        return SignalRService.this;
    }
}


/**
 * method for clients (activities)
 */


private void startSignalR() {
    Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());
    mInstance.setmHubConnection();
    mInstance.setHubProxy();
    ClientTransport clientTransport = new ServerSentEventsTransport(mInstance.mHubConnection.getLogger());
    SignalRFuture<Void> signalRFuture = mInstance.mHubConnection.start(clientTransport);

    try {
        signalRFuture.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        Log.e("SimpleSignalR", e.toString());
        return;
    }

    mInstance.sendMessage(MainActivity.unm,"Hello All!");

    String CLIENT_METHOD_BROADAST_MESSAGE = "recievedMessage";
    //String CLIENT_METHOD_BROADAST_MESSAGE = "messageReceived";
    mInstance.mHubProxy.on(CLIENT_METHOD_BROADAST_MESSAGE,
            new SubscriptionHandler2<String,LoginInfo>() {
                @Override
                public void run(final String msg,final LoginInfo loginInfo) {
                    final String finalMsg = loginInfo.FullName  + "  says " + loginInfo.Password;
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);
                    intent.putExtra("DATAPASSED", finalMsg);
                    sendBroadcast(intent);
                }
            }
            , String.class,LoginInfo.class);
}
}
```

After you will get calls from Service
Hope you will get what you need.

Comment: actually I'm .Net developer, when user call an Web API Url to get new fresh message is received if any Updates in server,  that is i need to develop like chat in SignalR , same  mechanism is works in android   ?

Comment: what is this MainActivity.unm?

Comment: @RiddhiShah Actually it was static variable `unm`  in MainActivity  for username .

Comment: okay thanks and I am getting this error 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.transport.NegotiationException: There was a problem in the negotiation with the server